# KDB Selecting rows of one table that have matching keys in a second table

Tags: join, key, kdb

Silly kdb question.  I want to select rows from t1 based on which keys in t2 match the columns in t1.  In the example below, the only `date`sym combos in t1 that appear in t2 are `d1`s3 and `d3`s4.  Thus, my resulting table t3 should just have these two rows.

```
t1:([]date:`d1`d2`d3`d3;sym:`s1`s2`s3`s4;price:100 200 300 400)
date    sym price
d1  s1  100
d2  s2  200
d3  s3  300
d3  s4  400


t2:2!([]date:`d1`d3`d3`d4;sym:`s1`s2`s4`s9;var1:`Blah`Blah`Blah`Blah;var2:`Blah`Blah`Blah`Blah)
    date sym | var1 var2
    d1  s1  Blah    Blah
    d3  s2  Blah    Blah
    d3  s4  Blah    Blah
    d4  s9  Blah    Blah


t3:([]date:`d1`d3;sym:`s1`s4;price:100 400)
date    sym price
d1  s1  100
d3  s4  400
```

One silly way of doing this is

```
delete var1,var2,... from t1 ij t2
```

Is there a cleaner way that doesnt involve having to manually delete all the non key columns of t2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is

```
q)select from t1 where ([] date;sym) in key t2
date sym price
--------------
d1   s1  100
d3   s4  400
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in case your t2 is keyed by a lot of columns and you don't feel like typing them out

```
t1 where (keys[t2]#t1) in key t2
```